# 'Implicit super constructor Object()' error and 'java.lang.Object can't be resolved' error when opening Java files

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I opened my computer in class today to work on some code and all of a sudden I got errors on every Java file I have. Just making new Java files it builds then gives me an error for some reason. This is strange cause just the other night I was working on it just fine.

[image: The screenshot]

I've tried to restart my laptop, restart VS code, clean the workspace and language server, make a new folder but nothing is working.